# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'NoneType'

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
@property
def total_duration_of_videos(self):
    videos_qs = self.videos.all()
    total_duration = datetime.timedelta(0,0,0)
    for video in videos_qs:
        total_duration += video.total_time
    hours, remainder = divmod(total_duration.seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return str(hours)+":"+str(minutes)+":"+str(seconds)
```

This is what i'm written here i was not unble to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some `video` in `videos_qs`, `video.total_time` is returning `None`. That's why you are getting the error.

To resolve the error change `total_duration += video.total_time` line to `total_duration += (video.total_time or datetime.timedelta(0,0,0))` as follows.

```
@property
def total_duration_of_videos(self):
    videos_qs = self.videos.all()
    total_duration = datetime.timedelta(0,0,0)
    for video in videos_qs:
        otal_duration += (video.total_time or datetime.timedelta(0,0,0))
    hours, remainder = divmod(total_duration.seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return str(hours)+":"+str(minutes)+":"+str(seconds)
```